# Drones always see through Improved Invisibility?

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5, illusion

Drones resist illusions with their object resistance, which is 15+. Thus even the simplest drone has at least 15 dice, and the sophisticated ones have even more, so unless one is rather lucky (or *very* good at illusions), they will very likely make the test and resist the spell.

Did I miss something important or is Improved Invisibility really almost useless against Drones?

Comment: In the end, I could not find any concrete evidence on how this actually has to be ruled. The book should have made this clearer like it was in 4th edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have read the rules right, drones will resist physical illusions with 15 dice or more. However it does not guarantee they will see through it. Magicians not specializing in illusions will have a hard time against them, but one can have 16+ dice to cast illusions with little effort, even with a starting character (magic 6 + spellcasting 6 + specialty:illusion 2 + mentor spirit 2).

Comment: Foci could also raise the dice pool.

Answer (score 2):

While you're right that a drone has 15+ Object Resistance, its Sensors only have 9 Object Resistance. So manipulating the drone's body with magic, or trying to Possess it, will face the 15 dice. But against an Illusion it normally only rolls 9 dice, since its sensors are what pierce the illusion.

Note that against 6 hits this gives the drone 2/47 chance and against 5 hits roughly 1/7 chance. So a single drone (or security camera) may fail, but add enough and the piercing chance rises.

(Which indeed means, as my players have discovered, that running over a highway at 200 km/h while invisible will still spook GridGuide.)

Comment: I would very much prefer that reading of the rules, since it allows a caster without a very strong specialization in illusions to use the spell successfully (without being completely secure from detection). However, is there any clarification in the rules for this to be the case?I have just reread the introduction to illusions in the basic rules which seems to be unclear / more in favor of using object resistance of the drone (not its sensor)...